# JSON Path Query Array Object

Tags: jquery, json, path, jsonpath

I have the following json snip and im trying to get the value of the last instance of boot_index in the block_device_mapping array.  I can get it to display only the block_device_mapping property, but am struggling to display any child object.

{
    "status" : "active",
    "image_location" : "snapshot",
    "block_device_mapping" : "[{\"guest_format\": null, \"boot_index\": 0, \"no_device\": null, \"image_id\": null, \"volume_id\": \"eb7cf04e-c671-449d-ac1a-xxxxxxxxxx\", \"device_name\": null, \"disk_bus\": null, \"volume_size\": null, \"source_type\": \"volume\", \"tag\": null, \"device_type\": \"disk\", \"snapshot_id\": null, \"destination_type\": \"volume\", \"delete_on_termination\": true}, {\"guest_format\": null, \"boot_index\": 1, \"no_device\": null, \"image_id\": null, \"volume_id\": \"2e31d59a-d005-4bdd-9921-xxxxxxxxx\", \"device_name\": null, \"disk_bus\": null, \"volume_size\": null, \"source_type\": \"volume\", \"tag\": null, \"device_type\": \"disk\", \"snapshot_id\": null, \"destination_type\": \"volume\", \"delete_on_termination\": true}, {\"guest_format\": null, \"boot_index\": 2, \"no_device\": null, \"image_id\": null, \"volume_id\": \"6cbc94dd-bd1f-4845-a528-xxxxxxxxxx\", \"device_name\": null, \"disk_bus\": null, \"volume_size\": null, \"source_type\": \"volume\", \"tag\": null, \"device_type\": \"disk\", \"snapshot_id\": null, \"destination_type\": \"volume\", \"delete_on_termination\": true}]",
    "visibility" : "private"
}

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

R

Comment: Are you stuck with that json?  It is not very well-structured (although it validates) because "block_device_mapping" is just one long string : "[{....},{...},{...}]"   Probably not what you intended.  And all those backslashes outside of the quotes.  I have reformulated your json below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See my **comment** above.

{
  "status": "active",
  "image_location": "snapshot",
  "block_device_mapping": [
    {
      "guest_format": null,
      "boot_index": 0,
      "no_device": null,
      "image_id": null,
      "volume_id": "eb7cf04e-c671-449d-ac1a-xxxxxxxxxx",
      "device_name": null,
      "disk_bus": null,
      "volume_size": null,
      "source_type": "volume",
      "tag": null,
      "device_type": "disk",
      "snapshot_id": null,
      "destination_type": "volume",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
    {
      "guest_format": null,
      "boot_index": 1,
      "no_device": null,
      "image_id": null,
      "volume_id": "2e31d59a-d005-4bdd-9921-xxxxxxxxx",
      "device_name": null,
      "disk_bus": null,
      "volume_size": null,
      "source_type": "volume",
      "tag": null,
      "device_type": "disk",
      "snapshot_id": null,
      "destination_type": "volume",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    },
    {
      "guest_format": null,
      "boot_index": 2,
      "no_device": null,
      "image_id": null,
      "volume_id": "6cbc94dd-bd1f-4845-a528-xxxxxxxxxx",
      "device_name": null,
      "disk_bus": null,
      "volume_size": null,
      "source_type": "volume",
      "tag": null,
      "device_type": "disk",
      "snapshot_id": null,
      "destination_type": "volume",
      "delete_on_termination": true
    }
  ],
  "visibility": "private"
}

Note that with my changes above, the json is much more useful.  Copy and paste it into something like [an online json viewer/editor](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/).  As my above comment indicates your "block_device_mapping" was just one long string : "[{....},{...},{...}]" and so not very json-like or helpful.

With the changes "block_device_mapping" now consists of three separate objects.

You can get to the last "boot_index" via someRootObject.block_device_mapping[2].boot_index  with"someRootObject" being whatever you are calling this entire json object in your code.